How to Skip Screens in a WhatsApp Flow Without Routing Model Errors?
I'm creating a flow in WhatsApp with an Endpoint, and in one of the actions, I need to go from Screen 1 directly to Screen 4 (skipping Screens 2 and 3).
This is necessary because I'm designing a support flow where the next screen depends on the user's choice.
However, I get an error. I couldn't quite understand the documentation on this - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/flows/reference/flowjson#routing-model
The error says: "Can't perform a transition from [Screen_1] to [Screen_4], because it doesn't satisfy provided routing_model."
Would the correct approach be to close the current Flow and start a new one, where Screen 4 is the first screen? That seems more like a Templates solution, but I prefer Flows for the visual design features.

Found a solution
You can set two or more screens in routing_model
"Screen_1": [
     "Screen_4", "Screen_5"
]


correct, you can define the routing model so that screen_1 can navigate to multiple screens as you did
